# How to use a Phototransistor and photodiode?

Tags: arduino, infrared, phototransistor

I don't expect my parents to spend the money required to get a ballistics chronometer for me so I decided it would be easier to make one from parts laying around in my room. I have the general plans worked out for a basic setup, which would be having the phototransistor/IR LEDs from two old computer mice set up in a linear configuration, spaced about a foot apart. Each assembly would be mounted on a breadboard connected to an Arduino, connected to my PC or a small LCD display. I have one problem though: This is my first time using a phototransistor. I know how a regular transistor works though. Can anybody give me a bit on insight on how this thing is to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like regular transistor a photo-transistor is made with a base, an emitter and a collector but the base is sensible to light allowing more or less current passing through it. So when the base is illuminated your photo-transistor is in saturation state like a regular one.

But in your application I think using a IR diode is not going to be enough. Maybe using a laser pointer is more effective.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.

Comment: If you want more infos : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode
If this answer is good for you don't forget to validate it !

Comment: Phototransistors have a lousy current transfer ratio; it is quite easy to get them out of saturation.

Comment: Laser pointer would be over-kill, You should use a slit, or small hole, in some material in front of the sensor to limit it's view range though. If you plan on using this outdoors, or anywhere there is a significant IR light source it will be tricky to make this reliable.